# Cannot read an m.file in Atom with octave although it works in Nteract

Tags: matlab, octave, jupyter, atom-editor, nteract

I installed the octave kernel for jupyter which works fine with `nteract`. In `Atom` I have the following packages installed: `language-matlab`, `language-matlab-octave`, `hydrogen` and `Script`. However when I load an .m file in Atom there is a red message for “No Kernel for grammar Matlab found”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the settings pane in Atom and navigate to the packages section.

[image: settings pane in atom]

Next, get to Hydrogen's settings page by searching for hydrogen then clicking Hydrogen.

[image: hydrogen in the settings pane]

Scroll down to the language mapping section and set `octave` (or whatever the kernel's name is) to `matlab` for the language:

[image: mapping octave to matlab in hydrogen]